# MongoDB Aggregate is not working as expected in Loopback

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

```
var media =  Userhistory.getDataSource().connector.collection('media');

      media.aggregate([
        { $match: { mediaStatus: 3  } },
        { $group: {
          _id: 1,
          totalSize: { $sum: "$mediaFileSize" },
        }}
      ], function(err, data) {
          console.log("data",data);
          //In data Iam getting AggregationCursor object
          //not the result
      });
```

I have used the above code to perform aggregation in loopback. My expected output of "data" in above code is the array of results, But I am getting AggregationCursor object

Note loopback-connector-mongodb version - "^3.4.1"

Comment: It is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get result using promise

```
media.aggregate([...]).then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```